# Slow UI construction

Tags: codenameone

I am making list of logos inside a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS. it is taking too long to be shown. The logos are loaded from the Storage. I am quite new on Codenameone, less than three months, and the code I use is below:

```
 public void makeList( ) {

        this.membersContainer.removeAll();

        int membersNo = this.members.size();

        ToastBar.showInfoMessage("Βρέθηκαν " + membersNo);
        for( Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry: this.members.entrySet() ) {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.setUIID("Label");
            b.setUnselectedStyle( this.itemStyle);

            Object[] s = entry.getValue();  
            try {

                ToastBar.showInfoMessage( s[0].toString() );
                b.setIcon( EncodedImage.create( Storage.getInstance().createInputStream( s[0].toString()) ) );
                b.addActionListener(e -> {
                    new MemberGui ( entry.getKey(), s[0].toString(), s[1].toString(), s[2].toString(), s[3].toString(), this ).show();
                });
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                ToastBar.showErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
            }
            this.membersContainer.add(b);


        }   

    }
```

I am wondering is there any other way to create this List of logos? Right now it takes more than 40 seconds to show this screen on iphone 7 plus.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InfiniteContainer` and only load 10 logos at a time. See https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html